# disable input using checkbox in angularjs

Tags: angular

I'm trying to disable a bunch of input fields using a checkbox, I've seen people do the exact same thing as me, but I can't seem to get it to work... I'm currently begging for sweet release.

I've tried using ngModel only to end up absolutely nowhere, getting the following errors:

> the attribute 'disabled' does not exists in the input field

or

> Got interpolation ({{}}) where expression was expected at column 0 in [{{isAanmeetVergoeding}} == false]

or the warning:

> It looks like you're using the disabled attribute with a reactive form
> directive. If you set disabled to true
> when you set up this control in your component class, the disabled attribute will actually be set in the DOM for
> you. We recommend using this approach to avoid 'changed after checked' errors.

my current build is this:

HTML:

```
{{isAanmeetVergoeding}}
  {{!isAanmeetVergoeding}}
  <div class="row form-inline">
    <div class="form-group mb-2 col-md-12 text-left">
      <div class="col-md-12" style="border-bottom: 0.5px solid lightgray;">
        <input type="checkbox" id="GroeperingDefinitieContractAVCheckbox" (change)="AVCheckboxChange($event.target.checked)" class="form-control" formControlName="av_used" [ngClass]="{'is-invalid': displayMessage.av_used}" /><label style="display:inline-flex; padding-left:5px;" for="GroeperingDefinitieContractAVCheckbox"><b> aanmeetvergoeding (AV) </b> </label>
        <span class="invalid-feedback">{{displayMessage.av_used}}</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row form-inline">
    <div class="form-group mb-2 col-md-11 text-left">
      <label class="col-md-3 col-form-label" for="GroeperingDefinitieContractBedragHB">bedrag HB</label>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <input type="number" id="GroeperingDefinitieContractBedragHB" [disabled]="(isAanmeetVergoeding == true)" class="form-control stretch" placeholder="0,00" formControlName="av_bedrag_hb" [ngClass]="{'is-invalid': displayMessage.av_bedrag_hb}" />
        <span class="invalid-feedback">{{displayMessage.av_bedrag_hb}}</span>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-1">

        <select id="GroeperingDefinitieContractBedragHBEenheid" [disabled]="{{isAanmeetVergoeding}} == false" class="form-control" formControlName="av_bedrag_eenheid_hb">
          <option [selected]="av_bedrag_eenheid_hb == e.Key" *ngFor="let e of eenheidOpties" [ngValue]="e.Key">
            {{ e.Value }}
          </option>
        </select>
        <span class="invalid-feedback">{{displayMessage.av_bedrag_eenheid_hb}}</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

TypeScript:

```
  public isAanmeetVergoeding: any;

  public AVCheckboxChange(event: any): void {
     console.log(event);
     this.inputDisabled = event;
     this.GroeperingDefinitieContractEditForm.valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
     this.isAanmeetVergoeding = this.inputDisabled;
   });
  }
```

and the worst part is, the variable that I am using works (see below)! but the disabling fields part is not...

[image]
[image]

please do not refrain to ask for any additional information required to pull me out of this hell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally solved it after 3 days using `[attr.disabled]` like:

```html
<input type="text" [attr.disabled]="isAanmeetvergoeding ? true : null" />
```

Comment: yes, a formControl can be disabled using [attr.disabled]="condition?true:null", using a directive or using disable method of a FormControl